# Cannot tell page that user is logged in

Tags: php

So I am starting with php and I have a very simple setup. I have 2 pages. One page is the logged in page, the other is the log in page. my issue right now is whenever i log in succesfully, the second page still thinks i am not logged in. here is my code:

I know i am loggin in correctly because it does not print "wrong" and i see the "got here" print before it goes to the next page.
log in page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php 
        session_start();
        ?>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <?php 
        if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
            ?>
            <script language="Javascript"> window.location.href="show.php";</script>
            <?php
        }?>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form method="post">
                Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="15" /><br />
                Password: <input type="password" name="pass" size="15" /><br />
                <input type="submit" name ="submit1" value="Login"/>
            </form>
        <?php 
            if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
                if (LOGGEDIN) {
                    print "GOT HERE";
                    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
                    ?>
                    <script language="Javascript"> window.location.href="show.php";</script>
                    <?php
                }
                else {
                    print "WRONG!";
                }
            }

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

logged in page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php session_start();?>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <?php 
        if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) {
            ?>
            <script language="Javascript"> window.location.href="index.php";</script>
            <?php
        }?>
    </head>
    <body>WELCOME
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't use `session_start()` after you've begun output.

Comment: `if (LOGGEDIN) {` what do you think this is doing?

Comment: that is not the actual if statement. I have mysql checks that get the login info from my database that i took out because of passwords n stuff. The check for the login works fine.

Comment: Checked your browsers cookie store? And for a like-named file in PHPs session dir? Enabled error_reporting? etc.

Comment: so we have to debug you script with out actully seeing it -that could be difficult

Comment: @Dagon My login check was not the issue. So that is not the problem i was having. I said "i know i log in correctly", so why would you need to know the statement that gets me inside the log in if i told you it gets me in there when it is supposed to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't you put your `session_start()` before any other code ?

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

Comment: wowoww. that was it. I thought as long as it was before body it worked. but then again this is my first night with php.